# What should I do to join two columns with different name but has the same data type, so that I can get something I need from one of the table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two table, [table a] and [table b]. So basically, I need work_week from [table a] therefore I want to join the columns together, shift_begin_datetime from [table a] and shift_start_datetime from [table b] as both of them have the same data type but they have different name.

```
[table a]                                   [table b]
| shift_begin_datetime | work_week |        | shift_start_datetime | ........ |
| 2002-06-29 07:00:00  |     34    |        | 2003-07-29 07:00:00  | ........ | 
| 2002-06-30 07:00:00  |     35    |        | 2003-07-30 07:00:00  | ........ | 
| 2002-06-31 07:00:00  |     36    |        | 2003-07-31 07:00:00  | ........ |
```

I want both of the column to be renamed as shift_start_dt and after combining the result should be something like this.

```
[result]
| shift_start_dt       |
| 2002-06-29 07:00:00  |           
| 2002-06-30 07:00:00  |            
| 2002-06-31 07:00:00  |      
| 2003-07-29 07:00:00  |
| 2003-07-30 07:00:00  |   
| 2003-07-31 07:00:00  |
```

And is it possible to display work_week and ........ (representing the rest of the data)?

```
| shift_start_dt       | work_week |   null?  |
| 2002-06-29 07:00:00  |     34    |   null?  |             
| 2002-06-30 07:00:00  |     35    |   null?  |            
| 2002-06-31 07:00:00  |     36    | ........ |       
| 2003-07-29 07:00:00  |    null?  | ........ |
| 2003-07-30 07:00:00  |    null?  | ........ |    
| 2003-07-31 07:00:00  |    null?  | ........ |
```

I was also wondering if there is no data for the certain column, will it return as null?

I have tried union all for both of the table into a temp table, but I do not know how can I get work_week out of it. But I think union cant allow me to get work_week out of it, therefore, I'm not sure what else solution I can do. Here's what I did:

```
select 
    shift_start_datetime
into #datetime
from
    (select distinct 
        shift_begin_datetime as shift_start_datetime
        from table a
        union all
    select distinct 
        shift_start_datetime as shift_start_datetime 
        from table b
    ) as dt
```

Comment: @JonasMetzler the data is huge so i wont be able to share it plus im just stating the ones that i need with the simple example. and the question was isit able to join two columns with different name but with the same data type. so for me i dont see the need to include all as i think the example should be enough for my question. my bad for the null part, the null with ? was me not sure on whether i will get anything back if its joined, therefore, i put null?.  the dots represents other column, as i dont need them so i didnt type them out properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this helps you too, `COALESCE` and `FULL OUTER JOIN` are used:

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.shift_begin_datetime, b.shift_start_datetime) AS shift_start_dt,
       a.work_week,
       b.otherFields
FROM tableA AS a
FULL OUTER JOIN tableB AS b 
ON a.shift_begin_datetime = b.shift_start_datetime
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: This is a very good and simple solution. If it is guanranteed that there are no date matches at all or even if there are we want two rows, we can change the `ON` clause to `ON 0 = 1` or the like, to make it obvious to the DBMS that it doesn't have to look for matches.

Comment: thank you so much user17443931 :) i will try it out!

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner: Thank you for the suggestion! I was thinking of using `UNION ALL` as well but I couldn't get the desired result, thank you for your solution as well!   @zibin: no problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

You want a union of the two data sets. You can select nulls where a column does not exist in one table, but the other. SQL Server is really picky when it comes to types (which can be really annoying at times), so you probably need to apply `CAST` in a lot of places to have the selected columns from the tables match.

The final query will lokk something like this:

```
select
  shift_begin_datetime as shift_start_dt,
  work_week,
  cast(null as varchar(100)) as b_name,
  cast(null as int) as b_amount
from table_a
union all
select 
  shift_start_datetime as shift_start_dt,
  null as work_week,
  name as b_name,
  amount as b_amount
from table_b
order by shift_start_dt;
```

Comment: thank you for your kind help, i did tried ur code out, but i think im getting errors on these parts, name as b_name and amount as b_amount. It says invalid column name. do i have to chang it to null?

Comment: This is an example. You said there are other columns you want to show. So, if table_b had a column called `name` it would probably be a `VARCHAR` column, and while you's select that column from table_b, you'd have to select a null cast to varchar from table_a. Same thing, if your table_b had some column called `amount`, which might be an integer. You'd select that column from table_b and select a null cast to int from table_a. Of course you must select the columns that actaully exist in your tables instead of my mock columns.

Comment: You can only accept one answer. I suggest you accept user17443931's one, because it is much simpler than my approach. Its only drawback is that it may be much slower with big tables, as a join is more work than a mere `UNION ALL`.

Comment: ahhhh ok i understand it already. thank you so much by the way :)